# How do we compare two trie for similarity?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, trie

I was just curious if there is a way to compare two tries data structure for similarities?

```
trie1                      trie2

   root                     root 
/     |                   /   |
m     b                   m   b
|     |                   |   |
a     o                   a   o
| \   |                   |   |
t  x  b                   x   b

def compare_trie(trie1, trie2):
    pass

Output["max","bob"]
```

Edit: So far I tried to implement a dfs algorithm, but struck on how to manage two stacks of the different tries

Code that I tried still struck by managing two stacks for two different tries:

```
def compareTrie(trie1, trie2):
    dfsStack = []
    result = []
    stack1 = [x for x in trie1.keys()]
    stack2 = [y for y in trie2.keys()]
    similar = list(set(stack1) & set(stack2))
    dfsStack.append((similar, result))
    while (dfsStack):
        current, result = dfsStack.pop()
        print(current, result)
        result.append(current)
        for c in current:
            trie1 = trie1[c]
            trie2 = trie2[c]
            st1 = [x for x in trie1.keys()]
            st2 = [x for x in trie2.keys()]
            simm = list(set(st1) & set(st2))
            dfsStack.append((simm, result))

    print(result)
```

Trie Implementation:

```
def create_trie(words):
    trie = {}
    for word in words:
        curr = trie
        for c in word:
            if c not in curr:
                curr[c] = {}
            curr = curr[c]
        # Mark the end of a word
        curr['#'] = True
    return trie


s1 = "mat max bob"
s2 = "max bob"

words1 = s1.split()
words2 = s2.split()

t1 = create_trie(words1)
t2 = create_trie(words2)
```

Comment: What's your measure of "similarity" here?

Comment: I mean just need to find the similar nodes in two tires

Comment: What rule defines whether two nodes are considered "similar"?

Comment: The question is pretty simple, but you should add your approach as well

Comment: If two nodes from different contains same letter then they are similar.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Is there a way" is merely an introduction to "how do I do it?", which is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I was thinking of doing DFS search but I confused about implementation

Comment: @Prune Well I am trying to do that, by far I tried to implement dfs but getting struck when maintaining and comparing two stacks for two different tries

Comment: @lolmeowqt add whatever approach you've come up with, gives credibility to your point and the question

Comment: Again, refer to the posting guidelines in my previous comment.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Add the code for the dfs approach you have used

Comment: @Prune Yes I agree, I was just wondering if this is even possible to do, I am not expecting a written solution to this.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I added some code I was trying

Comment: @lolmeowqt How are you defining the trie, add that as well. Using a class implementation is the best way for that, not using dictionaries

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Added my trie implementation

Comment: I see; you're simply looking for common keys between the two tries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea to use dfs was correct; however, you could've opted a simple recusive approach to solve the task at hand. Here's the recursive version:

```py
def create_trie(words):
    trie = {}
    for word in words:
        curr = trie
        for c in word:
            if c not in curr:
                curr[c] = {}
            curr = curr[c]
        # Mark the end of a word
        curr['#'] = True
    return trie

def compare(trie1, trie2, curr):
    for i in trie1.keys():
        if trie2.get(i, None):
            if i=="#":
                result.append(curr)
            else:
                compare(trie1[i], trie2[i], curr+i)
    

s1 = "mat max bob temp2 fg f r"
s2 = "max bob temp fg r c"

words1 = s1.split()
words2 = s2.split()

t1 = create_trie(words1)
t2 = create_trie(words2)
result = []
compare(t1, t2, "")
print(result)   #['max', 'bob', 'fg', 'r']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can replace recursion with one stack for current states. And create `result` array within `compare` method.

```
def compare(trie1, trie2):
    result = []
    stack = [(trie1, trie2, "")]
    while stack:
        t1, t2, curr = stack.pop()
        for i in t1:
            if i not in t2:
                continue
            if i == "#":
                result.append(curr)
            else:
                stack.append((t1[i], t2[i], curr + i))
    return result
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.  Most things are, since you're using a general-purpose language on a device that is just short of a Turing machine.

The trivial, brute-force way to do this is to traverse each trie, generating a set of all of its keys.  Take the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know I can use set but the main main motive was to save the space by not using set